# What eclipse plugin the project is required?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, svg

I have found this project sample. It says it is an eclipse project type but I am wondering what eclipse plugin does it require to be compiled successfully? I'd like to build the sample with my eclipse but I am not sure how should I prepare my eclipse to compile such kind of project? What additional libs etc... So I need your advice

Here is its structure screen shot

[image: project structure]

[project source...](http://code.google.com/p/vectomatic/source/browse/lib-gwt-svg-chess/tags/0.3.9/?r=350#0.3.9/src/main/java)

Any useful comment is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

That looks more like a maven project structure - check if it has a pom.xml.

Comment: So, what should I install to my eclipse to compile it? Is the GWT plugin enough?

Comment: Emm... I watched all project packages http://code.google.com/p/vectomatic/source/browse/lib-gwt-svg-chess/tags/0.3.9/?r=350#0.3.9/src/main/java and there is no pom.xml :( The thing is I am interested is... should I create "resources" and "java" folders manually or it is expected a plugin project structure generation?

Comment: ... because, as you can see, the project contains two roots it is com and org and it is quite unusual as for a simple gwt project isn't it? Moreover, it uses svg so is there should be a eclipse plugin installed? If there should so which one?

Comment: See all the natures in the [project.xml](http://code.google.com/p/vectomatic/source/browse/lib-gwt-svg-chess/tags/0.3.9/.project?r=350)? I see WST, GWT, EMF, Maven... so you need to have all these installed.

Answer (score 1):

In the [root  directory of the project](http://code.google.com/p/vectomatic/source/browse/lib-gwt-svg-chess/tags/0.3.9/?r=350#0.3.9%253Fstate%253Dclosed) , I found it has a  `pom.xml` , so it is a Maven based project.

Looking into `.project`  file (an eclipse project-specific file)   , it has the following :

```
 <nature>org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven2Nature</nature>
```

`org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven2Nature`  means that the project has the [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) (a maven pluign for eclipse)  nature  .Note that  after the version 0.12.1 ,  [m2eclipse project is moved to Eclipse Foundation](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/new-and-noteworthy.html) and become the part of Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) release .  The name of this nature becomes `org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature`

Besides ,I also found that there are some WTP-specified setting files (eg `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`) in the `.setting` folder . WTP is  included inside the 'Java EE Developers version' of eclipse by default.

So , this project is created by eclipse installed with the WTP  and the m2eclipse with the version at or before  0.12.1.

> how should I prepare my eclipse to compile such kind of project? What
>   additional libs etc.

As  it is a maven project , you don't have to include the additional libs explicitly . All the libs required are configured inside the `pom.xml` and maven will  download these libs for you.

For me , I would use an eclipse  installed with [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) , [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) ,[m2eclipse-wtp](http://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2011/06/23/m2eclipse-wtp-0130-new-noteworthy) and [GWT eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/download.html) . Then create a new maven war application , and only copy the `pom.xml` and the `src` folder  to the project .After that use the `m2eclipse` function  to update the download libs and those project-specified setting files.

Comment: Oh, I have just the eclipse helios 3.6 so is it OK or I should get the indigo one?

Comment: Is the http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/r eclipse OK as for this project?

Comment: "After that use the m2eclipse function to update the download libs and..." @Ken Chan Emm... could you share me a tutorial of that?

Comment: First configure the maven setting under `Preferences --> Maven` .Then right click the `project --> Maven` , and choose `update dependencies` to download the libs . Choose `Update project configurations` to update the project-specified setting files

Comment: I just wanted to ask ... why when I open the dialog as "Check out as Maven Project from SCM" I cannot choose any SCM type in its combobox because it is empty? :(

Comment: ...I have found this link http://vectomatic.googlecode.com/svn/lib-gwt-svg/trunk/ from here http://code.google.com/p/vectomatic/source/checkout and as I may think it may help me to import with maven but for some reason I cannot import all the same as the video tutorial shows http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/ I mean the SCM combobox is empty and here I need your advice what I could miss here?

Comment: I did not use the option "Check out as Maven Project from SCM" . As your project is stored in the SVN , I will first use the SVN client (eg `TortoiseSVN`) to grab the project source code into my harddisk.Then creating the project by choosing `Maven Project` , and copy the `pom.xml` and `src` into the created maven project

Comment: I ve added some connectors to maven and it worked. But now the pow.xml throws an error as "Missing artifact com.google:gwt-incubator-slider:jar:0.1" what does it means?

Comment: Maven will try to download the libs which are enclosed by `<dependency>` in `pom.xml` from your configured remote maven repository if this lib does not exist in your local maven repository.This error means that maven cannot find there are no `gwt-incubator-slider:jar` version 1.0 libs to download from the remote maven repository

Comment: so I do I must get the lib as "gwt-incubator-slider" and add in to the project manually? Will the error stop then?